# How to convert a list of dictionaries to a Pandas Dataframe with one of the values as column name?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where a column consists of a list of dictionaries, something like this-

```
    column1    column2
0   abc        [{key1:value_A, key2:value_1}, {key1:value_B, key2:value_2}, {key1:value_C, key2:value_3},...]
    .
    .
    .
n   xyz        [{key1:value_A, key2:value_4}, {key1:value_B, key2:value_5}, {key1:value_C, key2:value_6},...]
```

I want to convert this dataframe to something like this-

```
    column1    value_A    value_B    value_C ....
0   abc        value_1    value_2    value_3
    .
    .
    .
n   xyz        value_4    value_5    value_6
```

What is a fast and efficient way to do this?

You can use the following code snippet to generate the df -

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, [
    {'id': 1144801690551941, 'value': 20},
    {'id': 8202109018383881, 'value': 26},
    {'id': 3025222222235562, 'value': 37},
    {'id': 5834245818862827, 'value': 35},
    {'id': 4689782481420271, 'value': 27},
    {'id': 7385168421196875, 'value': 56},
    ]], [2, [
    {'id': 1144801690551941, 'value': 25},
    {'id': 8202109018383881, 'value': 26},
    {'id': 3025222222235562, 'value': 38},
    {'id': 5834245818862827, 'value': 35},
    {'id': 4689782481420271, 'value': 21},
    {'id': 7385168421196875, 'value': 53},
    ]], [3, [
    {'id': 1144801690551941, 'value': 20},
    {'id': 8202109018383881, 'value': 29},
    {'id': 3025222222235562, 'value': 37},
    {'id': 5834245818862827, 'value': 32},
    {'id': 4689782481420271, 'value': 27},
    {'id': 7385168421196875, 'value': 50},
    ]]], columns=['column1', 'column2'])
```

Which results to -

```
   column1  column2
0        1  [{'id': 1144801690551941, 'value': 20}, {'id':...
1        2  [{'id': 1144801690551941, 'value': 25}, {'id':...
2        3  [{'id': 1144801690551941, 'value': 20}, {'id':...
```

The output I expect-

```
    column1  1144801690551941  8202109018383881  3025222222235562 ...
0   1        20                26                37
1   2        25                26                38
2   3        20                29                37
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide an copy pastable [mre]

Comment: @Andreas Let me know if this help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the column2, use `tolist` and recreate a dataframe that you `stack` to get one dictionary {'id':...,'value':...} per row.

```
s = pd.DataFrame(df['column2'].tolist()).stack()
print(s)
# 0  0    {'id': 1144801690551941, 'value': 20}
#    1    {'id': 8202109018383881, 'value': 26}
#    2    {'id': 3025222222235562, 'value': 37}
#    3    {'id': 5834245818862827, 'value': 35}
#    4    {'id': 4689782481420271, 'value': 27}
#    5    {'id': 7385168421196875, 'value': 56}
# 1  0    {'id': 1144801690551941, 'value': 25}
#    1    {'id': 8202109018383881, 'value': 26}
```

Then from there, use again `tolist` on this Series `s` and create a Dataframe, ensure to keep the original index. Append the column id just created with `set_index`, and `unstack` to get all id number as column header. You get the wanted shape for the id-value. Just need to `join` to column1.

```
res = (
    df[['column1']]
      .join(pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), 
                         s.index.get_level_values(0)) # keep original index
              .set_index('id', append=True)
              ['value'].unstack()
              .rename_axis(columns=None))
)
```

and you get as expected

```
print(res)
   column1  1144801690551941  3025222222235562  4689782481420271  \
0        1                20                37                27   
1        2                25                38                21   
2        3                20                37                27   

   5834245818862827  7385168421196875  8202109018383881  
0                35                56                26  
1                35                53                26  
2                32                50                29
```

Answer (score 1):

You could explode the lists and then use `pd.json_normalize`:

```
df = df.explode('column2').reset_index()
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df['column2'])).drop('index', axis=1)
df = df.pivot_table(columns=['id'], index=['column1'], values=['value'])
df = df.droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
```

---

```
id       1144801690551941  3025222222235562  ...  7385168421196875  8202109018383881
column1                                      ...                                    
1                      20                37  ...                56                26
2                      25                38  ...                53                26
3                      20                37  ...                50                29
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert `column2` to dataframes in each cell:

```py
>>> df['column2'] = [pd.DataFrame(col) for col in df.column2]
>>> df
   column1   column2
   <int64>  <object>
0        1  <DF 6x2>
1        2  <DF 6x2>
2        3  <DF 6x2>
>>> df.column2[0]
                 id   value
            <int64> <int64>
0  1144801690551941      20
1  8202109018383881      26
2  3025222222235562      37
3  5834245818862827      35
4  4689782481420271      27
5  7385168421196875      56
```

2. Unnest the dataframes:

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, unnest, pivot_wider
>>> df = df >> unnest(f.column2)
>>> df
    column1                id   value
    <int64>           <int64> <int64>
0         1  1144801690551941      20
1         1  8202109018383881      26
2         1  3025222222235562      37
3         1  5834245818862827      35
4         1  4689782481420271      27
5         1  7385168421196875      56
6         2  1144801690551941      25
7         2  8202109018383881      26
8         2  3025222222235562      38
9         2  5834245818862827      35
10        2  4689782481420271      21
11        2  7385168421196875      53
12        3  1144801690551941      20
13        3  8202109018383881      29
14        3  3025222222235562      37
15        3  5834245818862827      32
16        3  4689782481420271      27
17        3  7385168421196875      50
```

3. `pivot_wider()`:

```py
>>> df >> pivot_wider(f.column1, names_from=f.id, values_from=f.value)
   column1  1144801690551941  3025222222235562  4689782481420271  5834245818862827  7385168421196875  8202109018383881
   <int64>           <int64>           <int64>           <int64>           <int64>           <int64>           <int64>
0        1                20                37                27                35                56                26
1        2                25                38                21                35                53                26
2        3                20                37                27                32                50                29
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is from 3 steps:

**Step 1: Expand Data of column 2**

So we are going to expand data in `column2` by using recursive - `.apply(pd.Series)`:

```
dfs = []

df_expand = df['column2'].apply(pd.Series)

for col in df_expand.columns:
    dfs.append(df_expand[col].apply(pd.Series))

df_temp = pd.concat(dfs)
```

This will result into:

|  | id | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1144801690551941 | 20 |
| 1 | 1144801690551941 | 25 |
| 2 | 1144801690551941 | 20 |
| 0 | 8202109018383881 | 26 |
| 1 | 8202109018383881 | 26 |
| 2 | 8202109018383881 | 29 |
| 0 | 3025222222235562 | 37 |

**Step 2: Expand Data from step 1**

In this step we will use `pd.pivot` to convert row values to columns. Finally we will reset the MultiIndex:

```py
df_final = pd.pivot(data=df_temp, columns=['id'], values=['value'])
df_final.columns = df_final.columns.droplevel(0)
```

This will result into:

|  | 1144801690551941 | 3025222222235562 | 4689782481420271 | 5834245818862827 | 7385168421196875 | 8202109018383881 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20 | 37 | 27 | 35 | 56 | 26 |
| 1 | 25 | 38 | 21 | 35 | 53 | 26 |
| 2 | 20 | 37 | 27 | 32 | 50 | 29 |

**Step 3: Form the final DataFrame**

For the final DataFrame we will merge the result from Step 2 with `column1` on index

```py
pd.merge(df['column1'], df_final, right_index=True, left_index=True)
```

|  | column1 | 1144801690551941 | 3025222222235562 | 4689782481420271 | 5834245818862827 | 7385168421196875 | 8202109018383881 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 20 | 37 | 27 | 35 | 56 | 26 |
| 1 | 2 | 25 | 38 | 21 | 35 | 53 | 26 |
| 2 | 3 | 20 | 37 | 27 | 32 | 50 | 29 |